# Unconventional method of using Git

Tags: git, gitlab, blame, git-blame

I am working on a specific use case of automating code mgmt using git. I am not certain if git has this feature built in, or there is a product out there that does this already. I appreciate if you could point me towards the right direction.

The idea is simple, and the process as follows: (I understand this may not be the conventional way of using Git, and is a specific use case)

1. A scheduler commits the code from a shared-repo between users to GitLab (using scheduler user_id)
2. The day after users go through the applied changes to the code (using a GUI interface) and pick the changes made by them,
3. A script\code modifies the commit to adjust the Git-Blame output based on users' entires in step 2 (this step may require breaking the commit to multiple commits and changing user Author)

Any help would be highly appreciated.

I did use 'git_blame_someone_else' code and a combination of rebasing\cherrypicking, however, I thought I might be trying too hard and this could be a build in feature in Git. (breaking commits and changing code Author)

Answer (score 2):

No, git does not have this feature built in. The closest I can think of is [interactive rebasing](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History), which can let you break one commit into several (and even give them different authors), but it's meant to be a manual process, not something you would generally do from a script.

To be fair, it seems horrendously inefficient to combine different people's commits into one, only to have to break those commits apart later. What I'd *actually* suggest doing is reexamining and questioning the reasons that the default git workflow, where different people's commits stay as separate commits, doesn't work for you. I suspect you may find a better solution to that higher-level problem such that you don't have to do what you're describing.

Answer (score 0):

About step 1 : how are modifications entered in the shared-repo ? how is the code "committed" from the shared-repo to gitlab ?

---

1. `gitlab` being a git server, it is perfectly suited for hosting a copy of your shared repo ;
2. the standard way to use a shared repo among users is : each user creates commits, and then push these commits to the shared repo ; using this standard workflow, each user is registered as the author of the commit they created ;
3. you can perfecty have several shared repositories, sharing stuff between repositories is genrally done by *pushing* or *pulling* from one copy to the other ; pusing and pulling do not alter the author of shared commits, so no extra action should be taken to have modifications mentionning their initial author.

Among points 1 2 and 3 above, which one do not match your current workflow ?
Could you please explain your use case in more details ?